# Firebase Firestore Error: abi49_0_0.com.facebook.react.bridge. ReadableNativeMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

Even though the error indicates that I'm passing something incorrectly, **I'm assuming it's a Firebase/React Native/Expo Go library or config issue for these following reasons**;

- Moved the code to app.tsx on startup and I get the same exact error.
- I've tried multiple iterations with getDoc, getDocs, setDocs, and I still get the same error.
- The error typically takes 20-30 seconds before it occurs.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Anyone ever encounter this error? I think I'll need to get in contact with Firebase team.

Answer (score 0):

you can retrieve all documents in a collection by omitting the `where()`   filter entirely:

```
const getStuff = async () => {
 const displayNameRef = collection (FIREBASE_FIRESTORE, 'users');
 const querySnapshot = await getDocs (displayNameRef)
 querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
 console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
 });
};
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

The problem was conflicting libraries. Three and Expo-three libraries were somehow conflicting or breaking firebase/firestore. Firebase/Firestore library was completely up to date. So I don't think it was down-grading any libraries for peer-dependencies to work. Not sure why those would conflict but they do for some reason.